# Modifying Dictionary in Django Session Does Not Modify Session

Tags: django, session

I am storing dictionaries in my session referenced by a string key:

```
>>> request.session['my_dict'] = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

The problem I encountered was that when I modified the dictionary directly, the value would not be changed during the next request:

```
>>> request.session['my_dict'].pop('c')
3
>>> request.session.has_key('c')
False
# looks okay...
...
# Next request
>>> request.session.has_key('c')
True
# what gives!
```

Comment: I can't believe I just spent one hour and a half tearing out debugging this before finding this question. Thank you for asking this question and thanks to all answers. You saved my nerves and the rest of my day.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[As the](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) [documentation states](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved), another option is to use

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST=True
```

which will make this happen every request anyway. Might be worth it if this happens a lot in your code; I'm guessing the occasional additional overhead wouldn't be much and it is far less than the potential problems from neglecting from including the

```
request.session.modified = True
```

line each time.

Comment: I just noticed that this also means a cookie will be sent each time; for sites with a lot of traffic I suppose this could pose a bandwidth issue.

Also, I'm not very familiar with how references work in terms of sessions, but what if you did something like:

current_dict=request.session['my_dict']
current_dict.pop('c')
request.session['my_dict']=current_dict

Comment: I think that would work, since by setting the top-level key of the session the session would notice the change.

Answer (score 19):

This problem is actually [documented behavior](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved).

It turns out that SessionBase is a dictionary-like object that keeps track of when you modify it's keys, and manually sets an attribute `modified` (there's also an `accessed`).  If you mess around with objects *within* those keys, however, SessionBase has no way to know that the objects are modified, and therefore your changes might not get stored in whatever backend you are using.  (I'm using a database backend; I presume this problem applies to all backends, though.)  This problem might not apply to models, since the backend is probably storing a reference to the model (and therefore would receive any changes when it loaded the model from the database), but the problem does apply to dictionaries (and perhaps any other base python types that must be stored entirely in the session store.)

The trick is that whenever you modify objects in the session that the session won't notice, you must explicitly tell the session that it is modified:

```
>>> request.session.modified = True
```

The way I got around this was to encapsulate any pop actions on the session into a method that takes care of the details (this method also accepts a view parameter so that session variables can be view-specific):

```
def session_pop(request, view, key, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Either returns and removes the value of the key from request.session, or,
    if request.session[key] is a list, returns the result of a pop on this
    list.
    Also, if view is not None, only looks within request.session[view.func_name]
    so that I can store view-specific session variables.
    """
    # figure out which dictionary we want to operate on.
    dicto = {}
    if view is None:
        dicto = request.session
    else:
        if request.session.has_key(view.func_name):
            dicto = request.session[view.func_name]

    if dicto.has_key(key):
    
        # This is redundant if `dicto == request.session`, but rather than
        #  duplicate the logic to test whether we popped a list underneath
        #  the root level of the session, (which is also determined by `view`)
        #  just explicitly set `modified`
        #  since we certainly modified the session here.
        request.session.modified = True
    
        # Return a non-list
        if not type(dicto[key]) == type(list()):
            return dicto.pop(key)
        
        # pop a list
        else:
            if len(dicto[key]) > 0:
                return dicto[key].pop()

    # Parse out a default from the args/kwargs
    if len(args) > 0:
        default = args[0]
    elif kwargs.has_key('default'):
        default = kwargs['default']
    else:
        # If there wasn't one, complain
        raise KeyError('Session does not have key "{0}" and no default was provided'.format(key))
    return default
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm not too surprised by this. I guess it's just like modifying the contents of a tuple:

```
a = (1,[2],3)
print a
>>> 1, [2], 3)

a[1] = 4
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
...  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
...  TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

print a
>>> 1, [2], 3)

a[1][0] = 4
print a
>>> 1, [4], 3)
```

But thanks anyway.

Comment: a) You're allowed to modify the contents of a dictionary. b) the problem is not whether or not it's possible to a given variable; the problem is that once it's modified it's not recognized as such by Django automatically