# django request that does not contains a key

Tags: ajax, django, session, key

First i want to thanks you for watching my post!
I have used django for two month for an enterprise project. And im a kind of french noob  in web developpement and in django developpment :D

here is my problem: in a view im setting a key in request.session but after a render_to_response and an ajax query this key just disapeared :(

here is the function where i set the key

```
def check(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    RequestContext(request)
    try:
        m = MsGnlMember.objects.get(mbr_nom=request.POST['username'])
    except (ObjectDoesNotExist):
        return render_to_response('login.html', {'BAD': True, 'username' : 'Unknown User'})
    if m.mbr_mdp == request.POST['mdp']:
Here ===>   request.session['MBR_INSTANCE'] = m

        return index(request)


def index(request):
username = request.session["MBR_INSTANCE"].mbr_nom
request.session.modified = True # does not fix my problem
getNote = GetNoteForm()
saveNote = SaveNoteForm()
search = SearchForm()
return render_to_response('index.html', {'FORM_GETNOTE' : getNote,
                                         'FORM_SAVENOTE' : saveNote,
                                         'FORM_SEARCH' : search,
                                         'USERNAME' : username},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

this code works pretty well (username is changed on index.html depending on the result of the query) but when im on the page index.html im launching a ajax query which is below:

```
def arbo_get_acts(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    if "MBR_INSTANCE" in request.session:
        acts = MsWriAct.objects.filter(act_mbr=request.session['MBR_INSTANCE'])        
        acts_serialised = serializers.serialize('json', acts)
        return HttpResponse(acts_serialised, 'application/json')
    else:     
        acts_serialised = {}            
        return HttpResponse(acts_serialised, 'application/json')
```

and i never enter in my if statement :'( snif snif
so please explain me what im doing wrong or what i don't understand

EDIT: Ok Everyone, yesterday i test my code at home and it worked pretty well. At work it continue to fail. After a long journey and hard labor i found. It made tilt when i was thinking that
"why it works at home and not at work". At home i m using Linux, at work windows. ........
First google search:
Here is the shame on me: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9084
File-based session does not store any data on Windows

T_T how to loose two days of development

Comment: Check whether you enter the arbo_get_acts function.
It's ajax so you can't see the server Response directly - check it in Firebug. It may be some CSRF validation issue.

Comment: thanx for answering me here is the output:
POST http://localhost:8000/index/arbo_get_acts/
 
200 OK
  175ms 
jquery....min.js (ligne 18)
En-têtesPost
Réponse
Content-Length 0
Content-Type application/json
Date Fri, 13 Jan 2012 14:59:54 GMT
Server WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2
Set-Cookie sessionid=c531a3b804eb2c4d6bf591e826ac387d; expires=Fri, 27-Jan-2012 14:59:54 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Vary Cookie

Comment: Hmmm! HttpResponse should return any content doesn't it?
May be `request.is_ajax()` returns False? put some prints to debug request and request.session may be. I've never used session directly in django - so I'm quite unable to help you if this is the case.

Comment: Well I've did some research in my code. Setting and getting session objects like the way you did works for me. Even in AJAX POSTs. 
I had to add this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax to pass CSRF validation - but without it the server returned 403, not 200 like it's in your case.

Comment: im using this ajax documentation code. i think that there is no problem with request.is_ajax because before using session i just did a MsWriAct.objects.all() inside this view and it worked pretty well, but now that i need session for specifics queries that fails. well im not at work right now i'll try to do the same at home to see if that works. You said that you have never used session directly  in django just for information how do you use session in django?

Comment: well auth mechanism is built in Django so I use `@login_required`, `request.user` etc. only - these off course are available because of sessions, but I meant that I didn't have an opportunity to put custom values to the session like you do. I've developed only simple web apps in Django. Although it doesn't matter - like I said in my previous comment - I've managed to put my value to the session by: `request.session['MBR_INSTANCE'] = 123` and read it in AJAX post by `if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    if "MBR_INSTANCE" in request.session:` - it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Ok Everyone, yesterday i tested my code at home and it worked pretty well. At work it continue to fail. After a long journey and hard labor i found. It made tilt when i was thinking that "why it works at home and not at work". At home i m using Linux, at work windows. ........ First google search: Here is the shame on me: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9084 File-based session does not store any data on Windows

T_T how to loose two days of development

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes to the session, you also need to set `request.session.modified = True` before returning the response.

Further information:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved
- [Modifying Dictionary in Django Session Does Not Modify Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166856/modifying-dictionary-in-django-session-does-not-modify-session)

Comment: but in my setting i set SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True