# Adding to session dictionary

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a view function which updates the users cart (session) on add and removal.

```
def shoppingCartAdd(request):
    data = json.loads(request.POST['post_data'])

    if 'shopping_cart' not in request.session: #<-- create the session dict
        request.session['shopping_cart'] = {}

    if data["action"] == "add":
        with open(MEDIA_ROOT + '/json/products.js', 'r') as json_file:
                products = json.loads(json_file.read()) #<-- json file that contains product information
        json_file.close()
        item = products["products"][data["id"]] #<-- get the item info from json

        #If the item is not in the session add it. Otherwise do something.        
        if data["id"] not in request.session['shopping_cart']: 
            request.session['shopping_cart'][data["id"]] = item
        else:
            print('Exists')
            #Do something else. 

    #Remove the item from the dict.
    if data["action"] == "remove":
        request.session['shopping_cart'].pop([data["id"]], None)


    context = {'shoppingCart' : request.session['shopping_cart']}    

    return JsonResponse(context)
```

My problem is that I cannot add more than two items to my dictinary. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. If I click on the first item it'll create the session and add  it properly, and if I try to add it again it'll print out "exists". But if I add a second and try to add it again, it will not print out "exists" on the 2nd item.

Here's a print of my session with two items. using `print(request.session['shopping_cart'])`

```
{
'38': {'name': 'hergh', 'price': 23, 'active': 'active', 'pk': 38, 'imageURL': '/media/gg_faUCQOg.jpg', 'type': 'sokker', 'amount': 13}, 
'39': {'name': 'dea', 'price': 1, 'active': 'active', 'pk': 39, 'imageURL': '/media/gg_6ECtbKE.jpg', 'type': 'sokker', 'amount': 1}
}
```

Comment: first thing: `json_file.close()` is redundant with the context manager (aka with statement) you use. And I'd expect it (I did not test) to end up with an exception being thrown, and the following code not being executed.

Comment: otherwise, your code is doing what you say you want it to do. My advice would be for you to add log points/printouts that follows the flow of code in between each statement, following how the variables are changing and check how and where things go wrong.

Comment: @zmo I tried debug it down. But didn't really get any results from it. From my console in browser I can see it'll only print out 2 items in the dict aswell.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166856/modifying-dictionary-in-django-session-does-not-modify-session?rq=1 ?

Comment: @zmo I had not. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved

> By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session has been modified – that is **if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted**.

You can set the SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST setting to True, this will force save the session on every request.