# My session isn't storing what i'm asking it to store, when I try to view whats in the session an empty list is returned

Tags: python, django, session

I am trying to add something to a session by performing a post request via a form, when I try to view what's in the session by going to a page and a empty list is returned (I see this []), I have looked around toher questions and tried adding this `request.session.modified = True` but it hasn't worked as I thought that the session may not have been saving. Can anyone suggest any possible solutions?

Views

```
def cart(request):
    cartSession = request.session['cart']

    context={
        'cartSession': cartSession
    }
    return render(request, "OsbourneSpiceWebsite/cart.html", context=context)

def menu(request):
    request.session['cart'] = []

    context = {
        "items": Menu.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, "OsbourneSpiceWebsite/menu.html", context)

def addToCart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session.modified = True
        itemID = request.POST['productId']
        getItemFromPost = Menu.objects.get(itemid=itemID)

        if getItemFromPost is None:
            return HttpResponse("Error there is no data")

        cartSession = request.session['cart']

        for item in cartSession:
            if item['Itemname'] == getItemFromPost.itemname:
                item['Qty'] += 1
                break
        else:
            cartSession.append({
                'Itemname': getItemFromPost.itemname,
                'Itemprice': int(getItemFromPost.itemprice),
                'Qty': 1
            })

        request.session['cart'] = cartSession

        context = {
            "cartSession": cartSession
        }
        request.session.modified = True

        return render(request, "OsbourneSpiceWebsite/cart.html", context=context)
```

Form

```
<form action="{% url 'addToCart' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="productId" type="hidden" value="{{ item.itemid }}">
    <div class="addToCartButtonContainer">
        <button aria-label="Add" class="addButton " type="submit">+</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Cart page (page that should display items in session)

```
{% block body %}

<h1>CART</h1>



    <h1>{{cartSession}}</h1>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you haven't tried it, there's [another potential fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2167451/833881).